# while Monitoring a folder using File::ChangeNotify module how can i get the file which got modifed

Tags: perl, file, monitor

```
#!/opt/perl_5.18.2/linux50/bin/perl

use strict;
#use warnings;

use File::ChangeNotify;

$| = 1;

my $watcher = File::ChangeNotify->instantiate_watcher(
    directories => [ '/var/icc_shantesh/logs' ],
    filter      => qr/\.log/,
);

while ( my @events = $watcher->wait_for_events ) {
    print "loop got executed\n";
    print "File name: $_\n";
}
```

I am using [`File::ChangeNotify`](http://metacpan.org/module/File::ChangeNotify) in the above code in my R&D environment. The script monitors a folder and informs whenever there is a change. I want to know the name of the file that has changed, and its updated content

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `@events` array has the information you want:

```
 while (my @events = $watcher->wait_for_events){
    print "loop got executed\n";
    foreach my $event (@events) {
        print "File name: " . $event->path . "\n";
    }
 }
```

The array contains [File::ChangeNotify::Event](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::ChangeNotify::Event) objects, and they have a `path` accessor for filename, and a `type` for what kind of change has been done.

You could look at the example on the man page and rewrite your code to be like that:

```
 for my $event ( $watcher->new_events() ) {
     print "File name: ", $event->path(), ' - ', $event->type(), "\n";
 }
```

`$_` is the default variable of perl, but when you explicit set the variable like you do in the loop (`my @events = ...`) `$_` is not being used.

Comment: ,Thanks for the answer. which worked well for me. and i have additional questions
1-> when in the another terminal if i modify the same it doesn't report.
any idea why this behavior ? 

2->   when i tried to modify the repcoll.log file 
$VAR1 = bless( {
                 'path' => '/var/icc_shantesh/logs/.repcoll.log.swp',
                 'type' => 'delete'
               }, 'File::ChangeNotify::Event' );
it is considering repcoll.log.swp i want the repcoll.log not some temp file.

And i really appreciate the help which made me move on my work so far.

Comment: did you have a look at my previous comment ?

Comment: Hi. 1. Is the problem that if you modify a file in another terminal on the same machine that it doesn't update? 2. You modify it with a editor that creates a .swp file while editing. It deletes this after editing. Change your filter to `qr/\.log$/` which means that the file needs to end in .log, instead of containing it.

Comment: 1. Yes you correct i am looking for  a solution for that as well !
2. Thanks it helped me eliminating swp file

Now i have new question are there any method that on the go can i grep all updated information from required files (ex:*.log) ?
i tried unix command tail -f it updates/informs you only when the file has been modified and saved !!

Comment: 1. ChangeNotifier should solve that, if not it sounds like a bug. 2. This sounds like a separate question.